# Capybara nested_form Poltergeist select action

Tags: select, rspec, capybara, nested-forms, poltergeist

I'm using the fantastic [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem to handle my nested attributes which works perfectly.

My problem occurs when i try to use Capybara/rspec with Poltergeist as a driver to run a few integration tests on my nested form's **select field.**

My test is as follows.

```
click_on "Add Field"    
find('input:last').set "Employee Code"   
find('select:last').select "Word"
```

I get the following error in rspec

```
Failure/Error: find('select:last').select "Word"
 Capybara::Poltergeist::ObsoleteNode:
   Capybara::Poltergeist::ObsoleteNode
```

When i print the html content before trying to find 'select:last', I'm able to see the correct html. Pasted below.

```
<input class="string required" id="source_model_attributes_attributes_1355377152026_field_name" label="Field Name" name="source[model_attributes_attributes][1355377152026][field_name]" placeholder="Field Name" size="50" type="text">
<select class="select required" id="source_model_attributes_attributes_1355377152026_field_type" label="Field Type" name="source[model_attributes_attributes][1355377152026][field_type]" prompt="Select Field Type">
<option value="">Select Field Type</option>
<option value="Word">Word</option>
<option value="Number">Number</option>
<option value="True or False">True or False</option>
<option value="Date &amp; Time">Date &amp; Time</option>
<option value="Date">Date</option>
<option value="Time">Time</option></select>
```

I'm using find, instead of fill_in as my html is generated dynamically with a timestamp attached to the id & name fields.

It might also be worth mentioning that I've had poor luck with Capybara's select Action which I tried to use like this.

```
select "Word", from: "Field Type"
```

Which fails with the error below.

```
Failure/Error: select "Word", from: "Field Type"
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot select option, no select box with id, name, or label 'Field Type' found
```

Capybara, for some reason, is not able to find the label, maybe because it's hidden from the actual form.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem right now... Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: First clue, it's not related to poltergeist as I still have it with other javascript drivers. Seems like a capybara issue..

Comment: Sorry, this was ages back. Don't even remember reporting it :)

Comment: I've had same problems and it seemed to have been related to the space in the label